# jQuery animate on image

Tags: jquery, slideup

I want to do exactly the same thing in my shop: http://www.templatemonster.com/demo/34477.html

Please hover your mouse on any bag. As you can see the short description with pink background is sliding from the bottom.

Here is where I am now: http://jsfiddle.net/THwuT/

The top 3 product are almost have it, but the one on the bottom showing description on first one. It happen because I gave them position:absolute, but I don't have different idea how to do this without this.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a new version of your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/THwuT/29/) with some things fixed( I'm really sorry I pressed update instead of fork :$). The problem you was having was that you didn't put position relative on the .product containers (every time you've a parent with position relative, the position absolute will align according that parent instead of the page).
Also I puted the mouseenter/mouseleave methods instead of the old ones under the .prod divs because when you get your mouse on the desc it had a strange effect. And I removed the slideUp/down for animates because the stop can mess that functions. 
For making that site effect you need to add a height to your product containers,a overflow hidden and animate the top of the msg instead of the height. Here there is a fiddle with that changes [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bEuNF/2/).

Comment: hey, @Chris this is a good solution by marspzb; also if you want will not use animate you might have to get the co-ordinate which will be something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/THwuT/75/ any ways +1 marspzb! cheers!

Comment: thank you @Tats_innit, I didn't know about the .closest() function.

Comment: Hi guys big thanks for help. Could you please help me to setup this functions with this code ? http://codepaste.net/cyvmmv  I don't know why but when I paste jquery code to this file everything disappear

Comment: have you tryied adding  type="text/javascript" to your script declaration?

Comment: Maybe you need to add {literal} Your script declarations{/literal}

Answer (score 0):

Try this code jquery animate problem will clear

http://jsfiddle.net/THwuT/62/

Comment: Thank you guys for your help. Mahipal yours resolution looks really nice, but I have a problem to make it work in prestashop, could you please have a look at this code and tell me what I am doing wrong. http://codepaste.net/s5ihxp   Actually when I paste this code to file, everything disappear